# Making a list item Read-Only

Tags: list, workflow

I have a SharePoint 2010 list with a Workflow behind it. I want to make the list items Read-Only after the Workflow approval. Is there a straight forward way of doing. Could I do it as a Workflow action?

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you running?

Comment: Yes. Use workflow action to remove the current permission set on item and then re-add the read permission

Comment: It's SharePoint 2010.

What workflow would it be?

Comment: In designer workflow you can use workflow action

Comment: You can use a workflow that is triggered on ItemChange, checks the value and changes the permissions accordingly. SharePoint 2010 workflows have a Workflow Action called "Replace List Item Permissions" that can change permissions. For more information, please refer the article. http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html